# Trying to send RPC with PunRPC (Unity and Photon) but getting error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rpc, photon

I am trying to make it where a certain number of players are required before the client sends everyone to the character select scene.

Within a function I have...

```
if (PhotonNetwork.PlayerList.Length == 1 & PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient == true)
{
    PhotonView PV = PhotonView.Get(this);
    PV.RPC("heroSelect", RpcTarget.All);
}
```

Further in my code I then change the scene with...

```
[PunRPC]
void heroSelect()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
}
```

I am getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" as an error on the line

```
PV.RPC("heroSelect", RpcTarget.All);
```

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the problem.

In your hierarchy create an empty. I called mine NetworkManager. Add your script as a component. (You've probably already done these two steps.)

The important bit is this.
Make sure you have a **Photon View** on your NetworkManager. Drag NetworkManager from the hierarchy onto **Observed Components** in the inspector. This should fix the error.

Comment: Drag netowrk manager to itself as an observed component? It is grayed out

Answer (score 0):

You can set Observable Search to Manual

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.
The problem was solved by attaching PhotonView Component to the GameObject.